# Ruby Shoes for non-trivial apps

Tags: ruby, gui, mvp

I've been taking a look at Ruby Shoes for GUI development with Ruby. So far, it's been a pretty good experience for making simple apps. However, I am quite worried about being able to write large scale applications with it. For example, how would I go about using MVP pattern with this framework?

For now, I have not been able to not make presentation concerns leak into the view because of the lack of some kind of "data binding". I have code that looks like this :

```
Shoes.app do
    @view = SampleView.new
    @presenter = SamplePresenter.new @view

    @label = para @view.sample_property

    button "Update sample_property" do
        @presenter.update_sample_property
    end
end
```

Here, the call to `@presenter.update_sample_property` updates `@view.sample_property` but the label is not updated accordingly.

For this to work, I would have to make `@presenter.update_sample_property` to return a string, and then call `@label.text = return_value`, but I think that would violate the MVP principle of not having presentation logic in the view.

I'm used to work in .Net with the MVP pattern so I don't know if the pattern applies correctly to Shoes like I tried to do.

Are there any resources out there for making non-trivial apps with Shoes? Especially using the MVP pattern or something similar?

EDIT : I took a look at [the shoebox](http://hackety.com/programs) to see what other people have achieved with the framework. Though I did not look through it extensively, at first sight it seems like they are all simple projects with no real purposes.

UPDATE : I've finally been able to come up with something that satisfies me. Oh, and by the way, I moved to green_shoes because it is all written in ruby and I can run it from the command line rather than from the Shoes application. Packaging is not an issue for me quite yet.

Comment: I don't understand why this was put on hold, and the reason is not even correct : "Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource". This is not what this question is asking. I was only looking for tips about using a particular library. If you read the question carefully, you would see that I'm not asking for alternatives at all. Anyway, I don't care, it was 1 year and a half ago.

Comment: Your question ends with *Are there any resources out there for making non-trivial apps with Shoes? Especially using the MVP pattern or something similar?*. That looks like a request for external resources to me.

Comment: @marco-fiset As I wanted to ask similar question, and you probably have written lots of code in Shoes, would you mind share some informations?

Comment: @DarekNędza Actually no, I wrote a very simple app with Shoes, then moved on with web development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the first page in the Shoes manual:

*Shoes is a tiny graphics toolkit. It's simple and straightforward. Shoes was born to be easy! Really, it was made for absolute beginners. There's really nothing to it.*

From this statement I would say that Shoes was not really designed with large-scale apps in mind.

You may be able to implement an MVP or MVC pattern with help from the ruby [observerable library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/observer/rdoc/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at the Observer pattern when I get home tonight. I want to use Shoes because it is very simple and easy to use. Is there a GUI framework for Ruby that would be more suited for large-scale applications ?

Comment: @marcof - Take a look at this [site](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/GUI_Toolkit_Modules). It basically compares a bunch of different frameworks. Hopefully one of them fits your needs.